# Connecting or mirroring a VS2013 TFS project to git

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I work on a project where the source code is hosted in the company's (non-git) TFS -- I get all the updates via TFS and also have to commit my code to their TFS. Now there are occasions when I can't login to the company VPN for quite some time, and thus don't have access to the TFS, but I'd still like to preserve my local changes.

A great way to do that would be by connecting/mirroring the same sources to a git server (which I would setup locally myself). A second benefit would be the possibility to work on the sources from several other systems that don't have access to the VPN/TFS, but could access the git server.

I need to retain the VS/TFS workflow/integration/features: commits, pulls, merging, shelving, annotations, code review requests, work items etc.

I don't need to automate the process or VS to "know" about git, using the cmdline git to update the git repo after a TFS get latest files from the server is fine; same goes for manually pulling changes out of the git repo and then committing the pending changes to TFS in VS.

Edit/update for clarification: I would like to keep the VS/TFS integration/workflow as is, as I need to access pretty much all of the TFS features within VS. If at all possible, the TFS versioning in VS should not be changed in any way. The additional git repo should be as separate as possible. Ideal solution would be if I simply tell git that the exact same source files are git version-controlled. But I'm a bit afraid that this will break other one or both TFS and git, when they both overwrite the same files.

Is this scenario possible in some way, without breaking Visual Studio's TFS managing, even when pulling changed sources out of git into the TFS managed solution?

Comment: Do you really need a *git server* in this setup?  Or do you only want to be able use git to snapshot some changes in your working directory that are just intermediate changes (which will eventually be checked in to TFS) while you are offline?  It sounds like you might be describing using Git as a sort of save buffer (if you will).

Comment: the idea of the additional git repo is having access to the sources from additional systems that cannot connect to the TFS in any way -- git would act as a gateway of getting updates from tfs via git onto the other systems, and changes made on the other systems back via git into the main system that can then commit the changes to the TFS. I know it's a kludge, but right now I'm manually syncing the sources between the systems with diffing tools, and that is not sustainable. and yes, the local commit history of git when offline is also a nice bonus.

Comment: I see; I did misunderstand your motivation and certainly it seems like git-tf or git-tfs would be helpful here, as @jessehouwing pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

Check out `git tf` here: https://gittf.codeplex.com/

It was made by Microsoft and allows you to push directly from a local git repository to a remote TFS source control server. You need to grab one branch into a local repo, but since Branching and Merging requires a server connection in TFS anyway, that doesn't feel like a big setback.

Using the Visual Studio Tools for Git (included in VS2013, [free download for VS2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c)) or the 3rd party [Git Source Control provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c) (works in 2010 as well), you'll retain many of the features in Visual Studio you're already used to, but you will need to drop to the commandline to push your changes back into TFS.

Comment: thanks for that answer. while that sounds like it would work, I'd like to keep it the other way around, if at all possible: keep the normal VS/TFS workflow/integration (for commits, pulls, merging, shelving, annotations, code review requests, work items etc), and add the git support externally. also, when I connect to the VPN for TFS access, I'm locked out of my LAN where I would host the git repo. This can be worked around... but as I mentioned above, the other way around would be a better solution.

Comment: You can host the git repo on your local system, no need to put it on a Lan. And you could use it side-by-side with a normal TFS workspace. Actually scripting `git tf` calls to regularly update your local git repo would be quite simple.

Comment: this looks pretty interesting, and I will take a closer look at it. but I'd still prefer a solution that doesn't change the direct VS/TFS integration: for example I don't think the automatic TFS source checkout upon editing the local file would work that way. If there is no practical solution for the way I'd like it to work I will come back to this suggestion.

Comment: Can you describe, in your original question, what you'd like your workflow to be in more detail? I'm having difficulty grasping exactly which features you want enabled when. You can't have both standard TFS checkouts and use Git at the same time...

Comment: I have a blog post that includes the ability to clone a TFVC repository: http://nakedalm.com/migrating-source-code-with-history-to-tfs-2012-with-git-tf/